# Comparing various (but not all) columns of two different sized dataframes and select only those rows from one dataframe where the conditions are true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two datframes that have different numbers of rows and well as different numbers of columns.

row_List1:

```
        date   team_home  team_away   goals_home   goals_away   shootout_win   competition
```

`1     2018-06-04   India      Kenya        3          0          NaN             Friendly 2018`
`2     2018-06-06   Armenia    Moldova      0          0          NaN             Friendly 2018`
`3     2018-06-09   Italy      Netherlands  1          1          NaN             Friendly 2018`

row_List2:

`date   team_home  team_away   goals_home   goals_away   shootout_win   competition    venue`

`1     2018-06-04   India      Kenya        3          0          NaN             Friendly 2018  Home`
`2     2018-06-05   USA        Pakistan     8          5          NaN             Friendly 2018  Nuetral`
`3     2018-06-06   Moldova    Armenia      0          0          NaN             Friendly 2018  Away`
`4     2018-06-07   India      Srilanka     2          0          NaN             Friendly 2018  Home`
`3     2018-06-09   Italy      Netherlands  1          1          NaN             Friendly 2018  Away`
`6     2018-06-04   India      Kenya        3          0          NaN             Friendly 2018  Home`

So row_List2 has more columns and more rows than row_List1.

row_List2 has venues of all matches. I need to delete all games from row_List2 which are not there in row_List1.

So basically I need to compare the date of both the dataframes, Compare team_home of row_List1 with both team_home and team_away of row_List2, and the same for team_away of row_List1.

I tried the below code:

```
# row_list1['venue'] = np.where(((row_list1['date'] == row_list2['date']) and (row_list1['team_home'] == row_list2['team_home'] or row_list1['team_home'] == row_list2['team_away']) and (row_list1['team_away'] == row_list2['team_away'] or row_list1['team_away'] == row_list2['team_home']) and (row_list1['goals_home'] == row_list2['goals_home'] or row_list1['goals_home'] == row_list2['goals_away']) and (row_list1['goals_away'] == row_list2['goals_away'] or row_list1['goals_away'] == row_list2['goals_home'])), row_list2['venue'], np.NaN)
```

These are the conditions I need but the above code gives me an error:

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

One more problem is that the team_home and team_away may be switched in row_List2. So I need to check:

if row_list1['team_home'] == row_list2['team_home'] or row_list1['team_home'] == row_list2['team_away']) and (row_list1['team_away'] == row_list2['team_away'] or row_list1['team_away'] == row_list2['team_home']) and (row_list1['goals_home'] == row_list2['goals_home'] or row_list1['goals_home'] == row_list2['goals_away']) and (row_list1['goals_away'] == row_list2['goals_away'] or row_list1['goals_away'] == row_list2['goals_home'])

What I want as output is:

row_List2:

```
        date   team_home  team_away   goals_home   goals_away   shootout_win   competition     venue
```

`1     2018-06-04   India      Kenya        3          0          NaN             Friendly 2018    Home`
`2     2018-06-06   Moldova    Armenia      0          0          NaN             Friendly 2018    Away`
`3     2018-06-09   Italy      Netherlands  1          1          NaN             Friendly 2018    Away`

Can Anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hacky but it works. Note that the Armenia-Moldova games don't actually match in your dataframes (they're flipped home/away). I had to `.fillna()` before performing the comparison because `np.nan` doesn't == `np.nan`.

```
>>> for df in [df1, df2]:
...    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

>>> df1[[df2.drop('venue', axis=1).eq(r).all(axis=1).any() for r in df1.itertuples(index=False)]]

    date    team_home   team_away   goals_home  goals_away  shootout_win    competition year
0   2018-06-04  India   Kenya   3   0   0.0 Friendly    2018
2   2018-06-09  Italy   Netherlands 1   1   0.0 Friendly    2018
```

Comment: Yes it is switched, but I need some condition which check team_home of row_List1 with both team_home and team_away of row_List2 and same for team_away, so I want some venue for the Armenia-Moldova game.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df = pd.merge(row_List1,row_List2.drop_duplicates(),how = 'left')
```

Output:

```
       date team_home    team_away  goals_home  goals_away  shootout_win  \
0  6/4/2018     India        Kenya           3           0           NaN   
1  6/6/2018   Armenia      Moldova           0           0           NaN   
2  6/9/2018     Italy  Netherlands           1           1           NaN   

  competition  year venue  
0    Friendly  2018  Home  
1    Friendly  2018   NaN  
2    Friendly  2018  Away
```